# What is the most efficient way to make an application handle hundreds of simultaneous file open requests from Windows Explorer in a single instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-explorer

When I select a bunch of files in Explorer and right click open them (or press enter) I want all the files to be passed to a single instance of my application. I've used named pipes before to pass arguments from secondary instances to an existing global instance, but it seems like doing this for hundreds of program instances simultaneously (not to mention actually loading the application hundreds of times) is far from optimal. Is there a way to get explorer to concatenate the arguments on its own?

edit: I found a copy of the Paint.net 3.36 source code and it uses a memory mapped file to communicate between instances. That seems even more bloated than named pipes though (although it's not as likely to open hundreds of images for editing).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with shell extension.

Check out [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
and
[Create Namespace Extensions for Windows Explorer with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx)

Comment: Ugh. Custom dynamic verbs are "discouraged" by MSDN. I  also can't tell if there's a way to associate the "Open" default action as a dynamic verb just using the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the shell extension so I went with the named pipes. It seems to perform reasonably well, especially since there seems to be a limit in Windows 7 of how many files you can open with multi-select (although this will solve that: [open-more-than-15-files-at-once-on-windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/300911/open-more-than-15-files-at-once-on-windows-7))

It took me forever to figure out how to get the timeout behavior to work (had to use a manual signal instead of AsyncWaitHandle). Hopefully this will save somebody some time:

```
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
// You may obtain a copy of the License at 
//
// http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
// limitations under the License.
//
// The Original Code is the IDPicker project.
//
// The Initial Developer of the Original Code is Matt Chambers.
//
// Copyright 2011 Vanderbilt University
//
// Contributor(s):
//
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// A handler for an application to consolidate arguments from multiple instances
/// (within a Timeout period) into a single instance.
/// </summary>
public sealed class SingleInstanceHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the Timeout period has elapsed: the single instance is launched with the consolidated argument list.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<SingleInstanceEventArgs> Launching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Time to wait in milliseconds for additional instances to add their arguments to the first instance's.
    /// </summary>
    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a handler for an application to consolidate arguments from multiple instances
    /// (within a Timeout period) into a single instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="uniqueID">A unique string for the application.</param>
    public SingleInstanceHandler (string uniqueID)
    {
        var rng = new Random(uniqueID.GetHashCode());
        byte[] ipcMutexGuidBytes = new byte[16];
        byte[] ipcNamedPipeGuidBytes = new byte[16];
        rng.NextBytes(ipcMutexGuidBytes);
        rng.NextBytes(ipcNamedPipeGuidBytes);
        ipcMutexGuid = new Guid(ipcMutexGuidBytes).ToString().Trim('{', '}');
        ipcNamedPipeGuid = new Guid(ipcNamedPipeGuidBytes).ToString().Trim('{', '}');

        Timeout = 500;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Launch a new instance using 'args' or consolidate 'args' into a recent instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Connect (string[] args)
    {
        if (Launching == null)
            return; // nothing to do

        // create global named mutex
        using (ipcMutex = new Mutex(false, ipcMutexGuid))
        {
            // if the global mutex is not locked, wait for args from additional instances
            if (ipcMutex.WaitOne(0))
                waitForAdditionalInstances(args);
            else
                sendArgsToExistingInstance(args);
        }
    }

    private void waitForAdditionalInstances (string[] args)
    {
        var accumulatedArgs = new List<string>(args);

        while (true)
        {
            var signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            using (var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(ipcNamedPipeGuid, PipeDirection.In, -1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
            {
                pipeServer.BeginWaitForConnection(x =>
                {
                    // if timed out, stop waiting for a connection
                    if (signal.WaitOne(0))
                    {
                        signal.Close();
                        return;
                    }

                    pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(x);
                    signal.Set();
                }, null);

                // no client connected to the pipe within the Timeout period
                if (!signal.WaitOne(Timeout, true))
                {
                    signal.Set();
                    break;
                }

                using (var sr = new StreamReader(pipeServer))
                {
                    int length = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
                        accumulatedArgs.Add(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }

            // new args have been added to accumulatedArgs, continue loop to listen for another client
        }

        Launching(this, new SingleInstanceEventArgs(accumulatedArgs.ToArray()));
    }

    private void sendArgsToExistingInstance (string[] args)
    {
        var pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", ipcNamedPipeGuid, PipeDirection.Out);

        // try to connect to the pipe server for the Timeout period
        try
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine(args.Length.ToString());
            foreach (string arg in args)
                sb.AppendLine(arg);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

            pipeClient.Connect(Timeout);

            // can this ever happen? if it does, don't handle it like a timeout exception
            if (!pipeClient.IsConnected)
                throw new Exception("did not throw exception");

            pipeClient.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (!e.Message.ToLower().Contains("time"))
                throw;

            // no server was running; launch a new instance
            Launching(this, new SingleInstanceEventArgs(args));
        }
    }

    private string ipcMutexGuid;
    private string ipcNamedPipeGuid;
    private Mutex ipcMutex;
}

/// <summary>
/// Stores the consolidated argument list from one or more instances of an application.
/// </summary>
public sealed class SingleInstanceEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public SingleInstanceEventArgs (string[] args) { Args = args; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The consolidated argument list from one or more instances of an application.
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Args { get; private set; }
}
```

How to use it:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var singleInstanceHandler = new SingleInstanceHandler(Application.ExecutablePath) { Timeout = 200 };
    singleInstanceHandler.Launching += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm(e.Args));
    };

    singleInstanceHandler.Connect(args);
}
```

Comment: This is a disastrous solution when opening thousands of files. It's not just slow, it will bring down the whole machine. I assume it's running out of handles or something. Anybody know how to address that?